# Random tuning set for custom model

Tags: microsoft-translator

I've made many models with different tuning sets (while ensuring there is no overlap between training, tuning, and testing sets) but not a single one has gotten a higher BLEU score than one of the randomly selected sets. Is it possible to see what sentences are in a random tuning set?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot see your randomly selected tuning set.